# TestClass Codecoverage coming in CodeCoverage Section

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, static

I have written a simple Trigger as part of my learning. As per my trigger based on all new Account created a Case is created using Trigger. I have written the Test Class as well and everything looks working fine.

I was going through the code coverage I got some doubts about the way I have written my Test class - I have written in 2 ways

1. TestClass_01 ---> Directly created Account in my Static TestMethod
2. TestClass_02 --> Used generic Call to create the Account from my static TestMethod.

In the second way I can see My test class also listed in Code Average and its 0 always

**TestClass_01**
[image: TestClass_01]

**TestClass_02**
[image: TestClass_02]

**Account Trigger**
[image: Account Trigger]

Can you tell me why the **TestClass** is coming in CodeCoverage section, I believe its wrong. Can you tell me whats wrong in my **TestClass_02** and how can I call a general method to do some generic action like User-Creation, Account-Creation etc.?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Eric Thanks... I was able to find the workaround from the link

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer from[Apex Code Coverage: Test classes are included with 0% in overall code coverage calculation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34489/apex-code-coverage-test-classes-are-included-with-0-in-overall-code-coverage-c)

and https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5k3AAC

Steps

1) In the Developer console run this Tooling API query

```
SELECT Id, ApexClassOrTriggerId, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name,
       NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered 
  FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
```

2) Select all results and hit delete

3) Run all tests